# Renaming a file in php with the date at the end

Tags: php, file, date, rename

I'm trying to rename a file with a specific date attached to the end of the file name.  For example: vertices_dly_jrnl_automation_25_June_2013.csv.

The date must be 1 day prior to the current date.

This is the error I'm receiving: Invalid Argument

Comment: Are you sure that the line giving you the Invalid Argument error? I almost always see that attached to a foreach loop, not something inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape your backslashes, so use \\ instead of \ everywhere

Comment: I tried this:
rename("C:\\Vertices_Reports\\Daily_Stats\\vertices_dly_jrnl_automation.csv", "C:\\Vertices_Reports\\Daily\\vertices_dly_jrnl_automation_" . date("d_M_Y", strtotime("-1 day")) . ".csv");